# 'union select -1) what does it mean?

Tags: sql-server

I am reading through some SQL Server stored procedures.
Please have a look at this one:

```
select top 1 t.Id
from (
    select SomeField1 as Id
    from dbo.SomeTable
    where SomeField2 = @someVariable
    union select -1 as Id
) t
```

This is how I understand it:

1. return first item returned by query
2. field SomeField1 will have an alias: Id
3. we select from table called SomeTable where SomeField2 equals @someVariable

As far I get it.

What does 'union select -1 as Id' do?

What is the meaning of the last line:

```
) t
```

here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does `union select -1 as Id` do?

It adds another record to the subquery so it's guaranteed to return a value if no records match the `where SomeField2 = @someVariable` clause.

> What is the meaning of the last line:  `') t'`

It's the closing paren of the subquery, which gives it the alias `t`.  It's equivalent to

```
) AS t
```

Comment: It could also return -1 if a record exists because union order is undefined. The query is buggy.

Comment: @usr - And quite likely it will if the union is implemented with a sort.

Comment: @MartinSmith are you saying that this query is buggy if union was implemented with a sort?

Comment: @JacekWojcik - No the query is probably buggy anyway (I can't think of any reason any one would intend its semantics) but assuming it is supposed to return `-1` for no match and `SomeField1` otherwise. And also assuming that the `SomeField1  as Id` is a positive integer (ids usually are) then the sort will order the `-1` first making it appear as if there was no match.